# How can I prevent functions and variables from being automatically cleared when I close Mathematica?

Tags: variable-definitions, memory, clear

The following happens with every notebook I make:

1. I define functions and variables.
2. When I quit Mathematica and reopen the notebook, all of those definitions have been cleared. The functions and variables I defined are blue'd out and I have to run all the lines again.

How can I prevent this from happening?

Follow-up question: Is there a way to share notebooks with other people such that the definitions are retained? When I send or receive a file, the definitions formerly established in the notebook are cleared out, exactly like the issue I have with reopening my own files.

I know I can Ctrl + A + Enter the notebook, but I'd like to know if there are alternatives.

Comment: Look at "DumpSave" and "Save"

Comment: If you use a Manipulate, you can choose to use the SaveDefinitions->True option.